# How to make asynchronious django requests?

Tags: python, django

I have few GET requests which I should send to 20  http addresses
The problem that's the whole pack of requests is loading very slow, I  want to be able to see the result for the finished requests already and then those requests that are slow or unresponsive should be appended to the final view result  later.
What is the simplest method of achiving this?

I have already tried asyncio
From this tutorial https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-make-parallel-async-http-requests-in-python-d0bd74780b8a
but it has nothing to do with django.
Here is my code
https://github.com/nuriyevn/django_mine/blob/master/monitor/views.py

And I get

```
SynchronousOnlyOperation at /monitor/
You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

http://194.0.52.235:9500/monitor/

Comment: The request/response cycle in Django is synchronous; you can't return a result page, then augment it later in the same cycle (aside from certain streaming responses). You may want to just kick off some asynchronous tasks using e.g. django-rq, django-q, or huey, then have your view show their statuses.

Comment: Will I able to refresh views after each request with those methods?  django-rq is a bit overwhelming. Thanks, let me try them!

Comment: Well, if you don't want to use background tasks (agreed, they make things more complex) and you're willing to delve a bit into doing this in frontend code, you could have a view that does the HTTP call to a given Instance and returns its status. The frontend can then use JavaScript to call that endpoint for all instances in series or in parallel, and update the user's view accordingly...

Comment: I don't want to move those part of the code into frontend , so probably I will go with django_q and mongo as a broker.   Will see what I get from this :)

Comment: There's no good reason to add MongoDB if you're not already using it.